# questions on multiple plots and multiple legend on python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following code, could any one help me fix it? I would like to have multiple legends on python numpy / matlab graph.

```
 import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    fig = plt.figure(1)
    x0 = np.array([[1,2,2,3]])
    x1 = np.array([[2,2,4,3]])
    y0 = np.array([[1,6,2,7]])
    y0 = np.array([[4,2,2,5]])
    p1= plt.scatter(x0,x1,color='blue',s=3)
    p2= plt.scatter(y0,y0,color='red',s=3)
    leg = plt.legend((p1,p2),('class0','class1'),fontsize=8)
    plt.show()
```

I want my following figure to be on the fig and have its own legend

```
    plt.hold(True)
    z0 = np.array([[11,16,13,17]])
    z1 = np.array([[13,16,12,17]])
    p3 = plt.scatter(z0,z1,color='k')
    plt.show()
```

How I should add a legend for `p3`?

Comment: Do you mean you want both plots side by side like this example? http://matplotlib.org/examples/color/color_cycle_demo.html

Comment: A possible solution is given.  Did you find another solution?  If so, you can post your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here I have all three scatterplots on the same figure with one legend in top-right and the other on bottom-right.

We can get both legends to show up by adding the first legend to the axes as described in the [matplotlib legend guide](http://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html#multiple-legends-on-the-same-axes):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(1)
x0 = np.array([[1,2,2,3]])
x1 = np.array([[2,2,4,3]])
y0 = np.array([[1,6,2,7]])
y0 = np.array([[4,2,2,5]])
p1= plt.scatter(x0,x1,color='blue',s=50, label='class0')
p2= plt.scatter(y0,y0,color='red',s=50, label='class1')
z0 = np.array([[11,16,13,17]])
z1 = np.array([[13,16,12,17]])
p3 = plt.scatter(z0,z1,color='k', s=75, label='class3')

leg = plt.legend(handles=[p1, p2], fontsize=8, loc=1)
ax = plt.gca().add_artist(leg)
plt.legend(handles=[p3], fontsize=8, loc=4)
plt.show()
```

[image]